# FAST corner detection in android Opencv: Corner points not drawn

Tags: java, android, opencv

I tried FAST corner detection in Android using Opencv4Android 2.4.6.
The keypoints are detected,but the view is not showing the drawn keypoints,or

```
Features2d.drawKeypoints
```

is not working,i dont know.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {


      MatOfKeyPoint points = new MatOfKeyPoint();


      Mat mat = inputFrame;
      FeatureDetector fast = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
      fast.detect(mat, points);


  Scalar redcolor = new Scalar(255,0,0);
  Mat mRgba= mat.clone();
  Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA,4);
  Core.line(mRgba, new Point(100, 100), new Point(300,300), new Scalar(0, 0, 255));

  Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, points, mRgba, redcolor, 3);


  return mRgba;

}
```

By logging ,i can see many keypoints are detected.but not drawn in the seen.
The line i tried to draw in the view is also displayed in the view,but not keypoints.

pls help.
Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer i found out from [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-opencv/co9Zv9pon30/6ybbS1rJpB0J)

The problem was with `Imgproc.cvtColor` .

> The problem is that unfortunately drawKeypoints() can't work with RGBA Mats, it accepts 8UC3 and 8UC1 only.
>   So if you'd like to call drawKeypoints(), you need convert the picture to RGB and then back to RGBA to display.

So i changed the code to `Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB,4);`

Now it is working fine,and problem of bluish color also removed

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with the **DrawMatchesFlags**, which is the last input in the **drawKeypoints** function.. Referring to the [function description](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html?highlight=drawkeypoints#drawkeypoints), you can see all the flags that are being used.. i would suggest that you use **DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT** if you don't want to go into the details..

Hope this helps.